# Dynamically Save Canvas Coordinates (Drawing) to PNG or JPEG using PHP

Tags: php, html, canvas, png, jpeg

I know a Canvas drawing can be saved as a PNG image using a modern browser such at Firefox 5 I need to do the same by converting the X and Y coordinates into a PNG file using PHP how would I go about that?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean creating images with php? [link](http://ir.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

You Can Start By:

```
http://ir.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php
```

If you want to flip your image then: [posted by xafford](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php#85992)

```
<?php

define ( 'IMAGE_FLIP_HORIZONTAL', 1 );
define ( 'IMAGE_FLIP_VERTICAL', 2 );
define ( 'IMAGE_FLIP_BOTH', 3 );

function ImageFlip ( $imgsrc, $mode )
{

    $width                        =    imagesx ( $imgsrc );
    $height                       =    imagesy ( $imgsrc );

    $src_x                        =    0;
    $src_y                        =    0;
    $src_width                    =    $width;
    $src_height                   =    $height;

    switch ( (int) $mode )
    {

        case IMAGE_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
            $src_y                =    $height;
            $src_height           =    -$height;
        break;

        case IMAGE_FLIP_VERTICAL:
            $src_x                =    $width;
            $src_width            =    -$width;
        break;

        case IMAGE_FLIP_BOTH:
            $src_x                =    $width;
            $src_y                =    $height;
            $src_width            =    -$width;
            $src_height           =    -$height;
        break;

        default:
            return $imgsrc;

    }

    $imgdest                    =    imagecreatetruecolor ( $width, $height );

    if ( imagecopyresampled ( $imgdest, $imgsrc, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $width, $height, $src_width, $src_height ) )
    {
        return $imgdest;
    }

    return $imgsrc;

}

?>
```

Comment: i think I found the solution http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/04/save-html5-canvas-data-as-image.html Will mess with it in the morning.  Thanks Pezhvak, time for me to hit the hay!

Comment: Ok all the above where not correct was looking for the following converting X an Y coordinates into an image dynamically.  IRC #php (caffinated) hooked it up with --> http://php.net/imagesetpixel Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

These having more function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php . here `nineslice` will be correct for you i think.